# Excel VBA - using left function with find

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the worksheet function "left" in conjunction with "find" to determine a string variable in VBA. However, excel interprets the find function as a VBA function, which yields an error message when resolving.

Below my code:

```
...
Else
    MSa = MSa & Left(Range("D22"), Find(".", Range("D22")) - 1) & " " & Range("D25").Value & "."
    Range("Q7").Value = MSa
End If
...
```

where MSa is a string. Can you please advise as to how I can best solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InStr method is the equivalent of the worksheet function Find, to use it:

```
MSa = MSa & Left(Range("D22"), InStr(Range("D22"), ".") - 1) & " " & Range("D25").Value & "."
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Find`. However I wouldn't use that. Read below.

So on Sheet1 I enter `abc.def` into cell A1.
In another cell I enter `=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)` and get the value `abc`.

To call the same functions in VBA I would write

```
variable = Left(Sheet1.[A1],Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(".",Sheet1.[A1])-1)
```

Calling Excel worksheet functions from VBA does have some disadvantages though (it's harder to debug and slower). It's better to use the native VBA function InStr which works much like the worksheet function Find. The parameters are in a different order, but the results are the same. So I would write

```
variable = Left(Sheet1.[A1],InStr(Sheet1.[A1],".")-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the worksheet function `Find` you need to fully qualify it as follows;

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Find
```

Using `Find` on its on and VBA will assume that it is a VBA function. Same goes for `match`.